# Is it important to memorize everything that goes into creating a blank win32 window

Tags: c++, winapi, directx, game-engine, game-physics

Currently i have a general idea of what every line of code in a blank win32 program but, if you were to sit me in a room with no a computer, mouse, keyboard and open notepad, i would not be able to write a win32 blank window. Also to add on that, I probably wouldn't remember every WNDCLASSEX member variables.

So do you believe that I should memorize every bit of syntax? Or is a general idea of every line of code good enough?

This question was inspired to me when my book asked my to copy and paste the code from the blank window to the new project. I thought to myself, "I wonder if successful game programmers write out the code for every part of their project".

I am currently reading Beginning 3D game programming with DirectX and i am getting the preliminaries out of the way.

Thank you for your insight.

Comment: I've done this a couple of times, I would say no. It is the least fun part of any graphics program. It is just boring boilerplate and MSDN is a quick google away.

Comment: It took me forever before I could make windows while setting all window class members and window styles I wanted without looking anything up. You can get away with setting a lot less, but it's easier not to try explicitly memorizing it. For DirectX, make a small wrapper and move on.

Comment: Wait, do you really type that boilerplate? Here in 2013 everything has "Insert code snippet" function! ;)

Comment: When I give interviews and try to measure  Win32 knowledge, I'd expect candidates to give a fairly high level overview of what's involved when creating a window and how messages are processed, but I absolutely would not expect them to memorize specific functions and arguments.

Answer (score 3):

Depends on what you are trying to do. The general answer is no, with some caveats. If you are making a general Windows program, and not a game like you've described, there are about a dozen other ways to make a window with less pain.

A lot of game developers simply keep a boilerplate project file with this stuff set up. It doesn't hurt to know what it means though. I have some Visual studio project files I use for games/visuals that I start from so I don't have to remember all of this.

Comment: i dont understand, why does this question deserve a -1. It is'nt some googleable question asking how to pass a pointer to a function... But thank you for answering my question

Answer (score 1):

Do you need to memorize it?  No.

Are you going to write that code out again for every program?  No.

Will you even copy+paste that into every program?  Probably not.

But understanding how it is done is essential to making effective use of a library that performs these mundane tasks for you.  You'll understand where the possible extension points are and what options are available.